# How to sort rows on basis of a specific column in a text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to sort data from a text file on basis of specific column section wise but I am not getting any solution. The data format is like below:

```
Section-1:
0  2
5  3
3  0
0  5
3  5
Section-2:
1  4
3  2
1  3
0  11
Section-3:
12  8
0   6
3   0
12  0
0   3
....
```

Now I want to apply sort on column-1 in each section, I have tried it lot but not getting any solution. If someone help me I will be really thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific with your problem.  "I have tried a lot" implies that you have code to post, with actual and expected results.  Please do so.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your current posting doesn't tell us whether you're having trouble reading from a file (should be a direct browser search), parsing the input into blocks and integers (post your attempt), or sorting the list (another direct lookup).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to find the blocks in the text:

```
import re 

with open(your_file, r) as f:
    blocks=re.findall(r'^(Section.*)\n([\s\S]*?(?=^Section|\Z))', f.read(), flags=re.M)
```

[Demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/Q0Cbmf/1/)

Then sort the blocks and print:

```
for h,s in blocks:
    print h
    print '\n'.join(sorted(s.splitlines(), key=lambda l:tuple(map(int,l.split()))))
```

That assumes you want to sort both by the first digit and the second so that `1  4` comes after `1  3`. If you want to only sort by the first digit and not change the order of the lines based on the second digit, then you would do:

```
for h,s in blocks:
    print h
    print '\n'.join(sorted(s.splitlines(), key=lambda l:int(l.split()[0])))
```

Comment: You would also need to add `tuple` to the sort key. `sorted(s.splitlines(), key=lambda l: tuple(map(int, l.split())))`

Comment: @RithinChalumuri: No, Python can sort lists as will as tuples. Try it!

Comment: yes python can sort lists/tuples. But, your lambda function is returning a map object and **neither** a list or tuple. Running the code results in the following error. `TypeError: unorderable types: map() < map()`.

Comment: @RithinChalumuri: Fair point for Python 3. Python 2 works as is (and it was tagged Python 2...) I will add that...

Comment: @dawg: Dear thanks alot for your kind and valuable help, your code helped me and  the problem is solved and also thanks to Rithin Chalumuri for your valuable suggestion.